# All windows minimized after login

Tags: macos, login, window-manager

I have a weird problem. Sometimes, directly after login, all windows are minimized.

The windows were not minimized when logging out. Most of the time they are restored to their previous position after logging in. But some of the time, they are all minimized.

It is usually all applications. Most commonly the applications in question are Google Chrome, iTerm, and Visual Studio Code.

macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, but this has happened on and off for several months.

Has this behavior been noted, or even better, has a fix been identified?